# Does Protobuf support Tuples?

Tags: c#, f#, protocol-buffers, grpc

I would like to stream a string tuple from a grpc Server.

I can't seem to find a clever way (if there is any) that this can be done. Have any of you had any luck with tuples in Protobuf?

Additional information:

I am using F#, and would like something corresponding

```
string * string
```

Comment: Note: `(string*string)` is `System.Tuple<string, string>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What library are you using? I had no problem doing it with [protobuf-net.Grpc](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/). My service looks like this:

```ml
member __.SubscribeTupleAsync() =
    asyncSeq {
        while true do
            let time = DateTime.Now
            yield string time.Minute, string time.Second
            do! Async.Sleep 1000
    } |> AsyncSeq.toAsyncEnum
```

And my client looks like this:

```ml
use http = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("http://localhost:10042")
let client = http.CreateGrpcService<ITimeService>()
async {
    for (min, sec) in client.SubscribeTupleAsync() |> AsyncSeq.ofAsyncEnum do
        printfn "%s, %s" min sec
} |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

The contract is:

```ml
[<ServiceContract>]
type ITimeService =
    abstract member SubscribeTupleAsync : unit -> IAsyncEnumerable<string * string>
```

The .proto file is:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package ProtobufCommon;
import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

message Tuple_String_String {
   string Item1 = 1;
   string Item2 = 2;
}
service TimeService {
   rpc SubscribeTuple (.google.protobuf.Empty) returns (stream Tuple_String_String);
}
```

And the output on the client is:

```
3, 26
3, 27
3, 28
3, 29
3, 30
3, 31
3, 32
3, 33
3, 34
3, 35
...
```

Comment: Seems like ive been doing it wrong, this helped alot cheers!

Comment: Great. Please accept the answer if you found it useful.